# I want to seperate a column by the numerical values within but it sees it as bool so I cant graph by value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a CSV that has one column on latitude. For the northern hemisphere I want the value it to only count all values more than zero, and south less than zero.

```
north_df = (df.iloc[:,7] > 0)

north_df.head()

south_df = (df.iloc[:,7] > 0)

south_df.head()
```

this code just gives me a true or false statement on wheter it is smaller than zero or not.  However I want to make a scatter plot of that Latitude along with other columns like max temp. Unfortunately when I make a scatter plot the value of the latitudes are either 1 or 0 rather all the latitudes 0 to -60 and 0 to 60

Comment: `north_df = df[df.iloc[:,7] > 0]`?

Comment: sorry, basically means Latitude that is northern (>0). I apologize for the lack of clarity

Comment: The issue is that `df.iloc[:,7] > 0` gives you a list of boolean values, in order to filter your dataframe and get a new data frame object you have to do `df[`df.iloc[:,7] > 0]`. Did you try that?